# Implicit partial differentiation along $x$ and $y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Answer the following for the surface $z = f(x, y)$ defined implicitly with $2yz + 2 = \ln (x + z)$.

1. Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface at $(2, 1, 1)$.
2. Identify a normal vector of the tangent plane found in 1. above.
3. Find the linearization $L(x, y)$ for $(x, y)$ near $(2, 1)$.
4. Use $L(x, y)$ found above to approximate $f(1.98, 1.02)$.

I need to start by finding the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ before I can do anything else. How do I do this?

Comment: Your statement $z=f(x,y)$ is wrong. It should be $f(x,y,z)=0$. Maybe you can try to see what happens for a simple and fake implicit function of the form $f(x,y)=y-x^2+1=0$?

Comment: haha could you tell my professor that its wrong? lol I am actually so confused

Comment: Well, in the expression $2yz+2=\ln(x+z)$, you cannot isolate $z$ such that $z=f(x,y)$ then, instead you have $f(x,y,z)=0$. How do you find the gradient of this?